# File put content text file one line per content

Tags: php

I have PHP script to save image link with tag and special html character.

output in browser

```
<img src="http://myweb.info/files/u_56de8bd7186b9_1.jpeg"alt="56de8bd751bfb" title="56de8bd751c3a" />
<img src="http://myweb.info/files/u_56de8bd7186b9_2.jpeg"alt="56de8bd751bfb" title="56de8bd751c3a" />
<img src="http://myweb.info/files/u_56de8bd7186b9_3.jpeg"alt="56de8bd751bfb" title="56de8bd751c3a" />
```

this 3 line.

But when I make code for save this in text file, output can't make 3 line. 
This output text file

```
<img src="http://myweb.info/files/u_56de8bd7186b9_1.jpeg"alt="
56de8bd751bfb" 
title="56de8bd751c3a" />
<img src="http://myweb.info/files/u_56de8bd7186b9_2.jpeg"alt="
56de8bd751bfb" 
title="56de8bd751c3a" />
<img src="http://myweb.info/files/u_56de8bd7186b9_3.jpeg"alt="
56de8bd751bfb" 
title="56de8bd751c3a" />
```

9 line.

How to make this same of browser view with 3 lines.Like this

```
<img src="http://myweb.info/files/u_56de8bd7186b9_1.jpeg"alt="56de8bd751bfb" title="56de8bd751c3a" />
<img src="http://myweb.info/files/u_56de8bd7186b9_2.jpeg"alt="56de8bd751bfb" title="56de8bd751c3a" />
<img src="http://myweb.info/files/u_56de8bd7186b9_3.jpeg"alt="56de8bd751bfb" title="56de8bd751c3a" />
```

this my code

```
$alt = ($nwname ."\n" .xxxx ."\n" .xxxx ."\n".uniqid() ) ;
$title = (xxxx ."\n" .xxxx .uniqid ());


$nsave = ('<img src=' .'"http://myweb.info/' .$newfname  .'"'  .'alt="' .$alt  .'"' ."\n" .'title="' .$title  .'"' ."\n"  .' /> ' );


$save = ($nsave) ."\r";

echo htmlspecialchars($save);

file_put_contents('filedat.txt',  $save,FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: may be the problem is with your text editor, check the `word wrap` setting.

Comment: Word wrapping doesn't matter at all in `HTML` code (with small exceptions, there is no need to mention them here). Concentrate on how the `HTML` you generate is rendered in the browser.

Comment: i use text editor on file manager in cpanel x , with encoding utf-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably caused by the `\n` in your code. Try this line instead (I've also removed some other obsolete string concatenations):

```
$nsave = '<img src="http://myweb.info/' . $newfname  . '" alt="' . $alt  . '" title="' . $title  . '"/> ';
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to concatenate two variables with a space character in between you can use:

```
$alt = $keyword1 . " " . $keyword2 . " " . uniqid()
```

Comment: yes this work, when i remove "\n"  function , this save for one line . thank, but this problem , in $alt and $title , i have function "\n" , how to make space without "\n" function ?? $alt = ($keyword1 ."\n" .$keyword2 .uniqid())

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but I guess what you are looking for is: `$alt = $keyword1 ." " .$keyword2 .uniqid()`

Comment: sorry for my bad english, same problem with ("\n") (." ") make new line after save in text , any idea ? like trim() function to make no space

Comment: i use http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php rtrim function , for fix this, now this code work fine , thank you  for your help

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of that \n in the $nsave declaration like so:

```
$nsave = ( '<img src="http://myweb.info/$newfname" alt="$alt" title="$title" />' );
```

Additionaly I would recommend you to use PHP_EOL to start a new line:

```
file_put_contents($filename, $nsave . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
```

Hope this helped you :)

Comment: yes this work, when i remove "\n"  function , this save for one line . thank, but this problem , in $alt and $title , i have function "\n" , how to make space without "\n" function ?? $alt = ($keyword1 ."\n" .$keyword2 .uniqid())

Comment: @vallez sorry but i don't understand you try to clarify your question

Comment: $alt = ($nwname ."\n" .xxxx ."\n" .xxxx ."\n".uniqid() ) ;
$title = (xxxx ."\n" .xxxx .uniqid ()); how to make space without "\n" function

Comment: I don't know if I'm missunderstanding you but... you could use just  
`$alt = ($nwname ." " .xxxx ." " .xxxx ." ".uniqid() ) `

Comment: sorry for my bad english,  same problem with ("\n")   (." ") make new line after save in text , any idea ? like trim() function to make no space

Comment: i use http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php rtrim function , for fix this, now code work fine  , thank you all for your help